# Adding an image to a TIF file in java?

Tags: java, file, jai

I will get one image from one location and TIF file from another location.
 I want to add that image to the TIF file at specified location. I tried but it is overriding. So can you help me?

Laxman chowdary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the image from the tiff file.
create a collection of all the tif images and pass the it to the TIFFEncodeParam class with:

setExtraImages.

read the javadoc on the exact struct need to pass to the method.

You will get a penalty of reading the file to the memory, but I don't see any other way.